# Verdana font is random height in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a sequence of simple divs with span containing "zero width char" (#8203) and span with text.

There is 1px difference in height, or offset of outer span when it's rendered in IE9.
What kind of optimisation might be causing this ?

Is there any css/javascript workaround to disable it?

```
...
<p>.</p>
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="outer">
        <span class="inner">&#8203;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="outer">
        <span class="inner">8203820382038203820382038203820382038203</span>
    </span>
</div>
<p>.</p>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srfCR/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an specific css file to fix this problem:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky issue. I’ll start from the practical solutions:

Instead of the ZERO WIDTH SPACE U+200B, `&#8203;`, use the `<wbr>` tag. It has no known drawbacks, except that it may irritate people who swear by standards. But due to some [issues](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#zwsp) in some browsers, it does not always have the desired effect (of allowing a direct line break), and it seems that to cover virtually all browsers, you would need this:

```
<wbr><a class=wbr></a>
```

with CSS code

```
.wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

A different approach is to wrap the zero width space in an element with reduced font size, e.g.

```
<span style="font-size: 0.8em">&#8203;</span>
```

or, simpler,

```
<small>&#8203;</small>
```

Then the explanations. The problem seems to appear on IE 9 in Quirks Mode only. My hypothesis is that in Quirks Mode, IE applies a more primitive approach to font management.

When it encounters a zero width space in Verdana text, it notices that Verdana does not have that character ([unlike most other common fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/fontsupport.htm)), and probably picks it up from the browser default font. This means Times New Roman by default. In that font, the zero width space is taller than Verdana characters are, causing added height requirements. This sounds unbelievable (it’s after all zero width, thus invisible), but the fact is the the problem disappears if I change the default font (in IE settings) to Arial.

One might think that `font-family: Verdana, Arial` thus helps. It does not, apparently because Quirks Mode IE is so primitive in dealing with fonts: it does not check the `font-family` list but falls back to its default font.

Making your page avoid [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) avoids the problem on IE 9, but I’m afraid some older versions of IE might still have the problem.